# Make dashboard charts reflect changes to saved query in SQL Lab

Tags: apache-superset

I have a saved query called "customer usage," which forms the basis of my "usage metrics" dashboard, a prototype. In this query, I add usage data from different customers as they come in (all tables have identical fields). In other words, I append new data with UNION ALL.

When I reload my "usage metrics dashboard," I do not see the newly appended data.

How can I make sure all charts in the dashboard will consider new data without rebuilding it each time? I tried to "change" and "edit" the datasource through the "Explore Chart" feature, but I cannot figure out how to point the chart to a new or updated saved query. Where might this option exist?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd be remiss if I didn't bring up the topic of your data structure: it seems like an antipattern. As your business grows, your schema will grow. Instead, you might consider a pattern in which customers are added without schema changes (just more rows). My apologies for the unsolicited advice (knowing nothing about your business).

In your chart view, you can click `Datasource` > `Settings` and under `Advanced` you should see your editable SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in 0.38 it should be much easier to go and edit the SQL in a "virtual dataset" that has been created using the "Explore" flow in SQL Lab.